# How to send an image with a Java server to an Android device

Tags: java, android, image, sockets, byte

I'm trying to send a picture with a Java server, hosted on my computer to an Android device. But when the picture arrives to the phone, it is cut: a small picture can be read (4ko) but with a 43ko picture, just the third of the picture is visible.

Server :

```
File f = new File("img.jpg");
BufferedImage buffer = ImageIO.read(f); 

ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(port);
Socket sock = server.accept();

ImageIO.write(buffer,"JPG",sock.getOutputStream());
```

Android :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

     try {
         StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
         StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

         Socket sock = new Socket(ip, port);

         Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), BitmapFactory.decodeStream(sock.getInputStream()));

         ImageView iv = findViewById(R.id.iv);

         iv.setImageDrawable(d);

    } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use any Image View library to preview Image.Hope it will work

Comment: By inform me on an View library to preview Image, I see that is only use with a path in the android device and not by byte stream with socket. Have you got any link to understand what do you mean?

Comment: picasso or glide any one you can use  for image preview or check this link:-https://github.com/stfalcon-studio/StfalconImageViewer